# Unable to update or install new Anaconda package nor update Conda root

Tags: python, anaconda

I am not able to install any new package in Anaconda (Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64), and also not able to update its root.

Executing command like below:

`conda update -n root conda`

Is trowing following errors:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  conda                                       4.7.10-py37_0 --> 4.7.12-py37_0


# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 308, in install
        handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 337, in handle_txn
        unlink_link_transaction.execute()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 240, in execute
        self.verify()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 227, in verify
        exceptions = self._verify(self.prefix_setups, self.prefix_action_groups)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 563, in _verify
        if future.result():
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 383, in _verify_individual_level
        error_result = axn.verify()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 957, in verify
        touch(user_environments_txt_file, mkdir=True, sudo_safe=True)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\update.py", line 107, in touch
        mkdir_p_sudo_safe(dirpath)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\__init__.py", line 82, in mkdir_p_sudo_safe
        mkdir_p_sudo_safe(base_dir)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\__init__.py", line 82, in mkdir_p_sudo_safe
        mkdir_p_sudo_safe(base_dir)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\__init__.py", line 82, in mkdir_p_sudo_safe
        mkdir_p_sudo_safe(base_dir)
      [Previous line repeated 984 more times]
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\__init__.py", line 80, in mkdir_p_sudo_safe
        base_dir = dirname(path)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 221, in dirname
        return split(p)[0]
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 184, in split
        seps = _get_bothseps(p)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 35, in _get_bothseps
        if isinstance(path, bytes):
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

`$ C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update -n root conda`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\
                     PATH=C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\u
                          sr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\bin;
                          C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\u
                          sr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\bin;
                          C:\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\clien
                          t_1\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Integrity\IntegrityClient10\bin;C:\Prog
                          ramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
                          \System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Integrity\Toolkit\mksnt;C:\Program
                          Files\Calibre2;C:\Program Files\MIT\Kerberos\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\BaseX\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Airtame;C:\Program Files\FME_2018_64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
                          VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin;C:\Windows\System32;
                          C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerSh
                          ell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
                          Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx64\x64
                          ;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\
                          usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Python3\Scrip
                          ts;C:\Python3;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
                          Community Edition 2019.2.2\bin
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Users\anderson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\
                          WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\M
                          odules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : U:\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.7.10
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=9.1
       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          U:\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\anderson\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          U:\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\anderson\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix it? **Re-installation of whole Anaconda package is not fixing it**. I have been using Anaconda over 2 years and have this problem since some recent upgrade. I run command as administrator. What seem to bogus is the "U:\" path. I don't have such drive and never selected it during installation.

When I run this cmd:

```
conda config --set report_errors true
```

I get this error:

```
CondaError: Cannot write to condarc file at U:\.condarc
Caused by FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

My "condarc" file is on "C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.7.10-py37_0\info\test\tests" so why is it looking for it on "U:\.condarc" directory.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was caused by presence of Environment Variable "HOME" with Value "U:\" which has been set like this by some unknown actions in the past. Changing it to "C:\Users\anderson" fixed issue.